# DOM Javascript: Como puedo agregar elementos de un Array dentro de una etiqueta como elementos independientes?

Tags: javascript, eventos, dom

tengo un ejercicio en el cual se me pide agregar dentro de una etiqueta `<select> </select>` distintos paises como `<option></option>` para poder desplegar una lista, pero debo agregarlos mediante javascript utilizando DOM.
Mi código es el siguiente:

```
window.onload = function() {
    let countries = ["USA", "France", "Italy", "Brazil", "Colombia", "Belize", "Venezuela"];
    // your code here

    let optionTag = document.createElement("option");
    document.querySelector("#mySelect").appendChild(optionTag);
    optionTag.innerHTML = countries;
};
```

El problema con mi código es que estoy agregando el array completo como si fuera solo 1 opcion dentro de la etiqueta `<select></select>` y no cada pais por separado.
El siguiente es mi codigo HTML.

```
<body>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="-1">Select your country</option>
        </select>
        <button onClick="alert('asdasd');">Hello</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = function() {
    let countries = ["USA", "France", "Italy", "Brazil", "Colombia", "Belize", "Venezuela"];
    // your code here

    
    countries.forEach(element => {
       let optionTag = document.createElement("option");
    document.querySelector("#mySelect").appendChild(optionTag);
    optionTag.innerHTML = element;
    });
   
};
```

```html
<body>
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="-1">Select your country</option>
        </select>
        <button onClick="alert('asdasd');">Hello</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
```

Recuerda que con JS puedes iterar sobre tus arreglos y generar una funcion flecha con tus acciones:

```
Array.foreach(element=>{/*TODO*/})
```